# django python: optimatizing db postgresql queries

Tags: python, django, algorithm, postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following postgres db

```
class Prescription(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField()
    patient_name = models.CharField()

class PrescriptionLine(TimeStampedModel):
    prescription = models.ForeignKey(Prescription, related_name="prescriptionlines")
    pill = models.ForeignKey(Pill, related_name='prescriptionlines')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Pill(TimeStampedModel):
    pill_category = models.ForeignKey(PillCategory, related_name='pills')

class PillCategory(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField()
```

**Code to Extract data**

```
def export_on_excel(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    ps = {}
    for p in queryset.prefetch_related('plines'):
        p_detail = {}
        for pline in p.prescriptionlines.all():            
            p_detail[pline.pill.pill_category.name] = pline.quantity
            p_detail['patient_name'] = p.patient_name
        ps[p.name] = p_detail
```

Using the above code, I have extracted 3 different prescriptions(A,B,C) with different number of prescriptionlines in dictionary.

```
ps = {
    Prescription A : {'name': 'A', 'patient_name': 'David', 'pill X': '4g', 'pill Y': '6g', 'pill Z': '10g'},
    Prescription B : {'name': 'B', 'patient_name': 'James', 'pill U': '2g', 'pill X': '6g', 'pill Z': '3g'},
    Prescription C : {'name': 'C', 'patient_name': 'Mary', 'pill S': '2g', 'pill T': '6g', 'pill Y': '3g', 'pill Z': '4g'}
}
```

Above data should be plotted into excel file as following table with the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ps).fillna('')
df.to_excel('prescriptions.xls')
```

Table

```
|              | Prescription A| Prescription B | Prescription C |
| patient_name |     David     |     James      |     Mary       | 
| --------     |:-------------:| --------------:|----------------|
| Pill S       |               |                |       2g       |
| Pill T       |               |                |       6g       |
| Pill U       |               |      2g        |                |
| Pill X       |    4g         |      6g        |                |
| Pill Y       |    6g         |                |       3g       |
| Pill Z       |    10g        |      3g        |       4g       |
```

========================================================================

***Question***

1. I have this feeling that the Extract code is not a very good code, because it has "for-loop-within-for-loop" and "too-many-queries". Being new to both django and algorithm-wise. Any suggestions on code optimization? Thanks in advance.